# angular redirect to other page and come back to the original page

Tags: angularjs, redirect, routes

my code is like this:
I have routes for A, B and C. so there are separate URLs for them, i.e. localhost:8080/A, localhost:8080/B and localhost:8080/C.

```
$stateProvider.state('A', {url:'/A', template:..., controller:...})
              .state('B', {url:'/B', template:..., controller:...})
              .state('C', {url:'/C', template:..., controller:...})
```

when I am on localhost:8080/A, and there is a payment flow which has 4 steps.
this is the way how I do payment flow:

```
<div ng-show="step == 1">
   ...
</div>
<div ng-show="step == 2">
   ...
</div>
<div ng-show="step == 3">
   ...
</div>
<div ng-show="step == 4">
   ...
</div>
```

when I am on step 3, I need to send a request with a URL(if the verification is successful, it would go to this URL) to third party to verify the credit card, and jump to their page, and if it is successful, the page should goes back to the original page (step 3 on localhost:8080/A).

how to achieve that? because step 3 does not have unique URL. the only option I know is to create a unique URL for step3, i.e. localhost:8080/step3. Then I need to do a lot of work to retrieve the HTML as well as controller code from A.
any better solution?

Comment: Add a child state that has `/:step` in url instead of using `ng-show`. Use `$stateParams.step` to determine which step it is and thus the templateUrl or even what to show

Comment: Go through ui-router demo and docs again to see how this is done